# I am getting error in console "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."

Tags: reactjs, django, server, cloud, nginx-config

I am working on a site that has a back-end with django and a front-end with react js, it was running well locally, but when I run the command on the cloud server, I get the error "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app".

JavaScript is enabled in the browser, I also tried different browsers. But I get the same error in all browsers.

Please someone help me to overcome this error.